# Collision detection between image and drawables

Tags: collision-detection, android-studio

I'm trying to collide my `ball_1` to `greengreen` drawable. How can I determine the collision?

```
public  class MainActivity extends Activity  implements Runnable{

    private Imageview ball1

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ball1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball_1);
        Drawable gr1 = new Drawable(R.drawable.greengreen)

        public void run() {
            startballanimation();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//trying to use an if else statement here to collide imageview ball1 to drawable"greengreen"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a huge number of things wrong with your code. I suggest you learn about multithreading in android before you try any kind of collision detection.

Comment: Take no offense but it would seem you are being a bit ambitious with what you are looking to achieve based on what you have posted. [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153355/location-of-drawables/153577?noredirect=1#comment273066_153577) I have answered a question that is practically the same however as the comment on the post suggests; I think you should look into threading and sort the infrastructure of the program before detecting collisions. Best of luck!