# Location of drawables

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the location of a drawable in Android Studio?

Example: `drawable.getLocationonScreen();`

I want to use it for collision detection.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the official documentation of [Android - Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable)? There's many interesting functions, like `getBounds` that could help you find the point on screen.

Answer (score 1):

If its for a player sprite you can create an object for the drawable (such as a player class) and create a Rect based on the drawable dimensions, this can be used to check for collisions using the Intersecting method. Is this what you are looking for? I can provide some example code if needed.

**Edit:** Examples and explanation.

For this method I would recommend creating separate classes for the objects you're checking. In this example I will use a player and enemy.
In both the player and enemy class you will define a bitmap for the sprite and then create a Rect based on the sprite: `rect = new Rect(x, y, x+sprite.getWidth(), y+sprite.getHeight());`. Once you have done this for both the player and sprite you will want to create a thread in your logic class and use it to check the following statement:

```
if (Rect.intersects(player.getRect(), enemy.getRect())){
    //Collision between player and enemy.
}
```

Detecting a collision between two objects is as simple as this.It will be more complicated when you want to detect collisions between multiple different items (which is what I assume this will lead to). In order to do this I recomend that you create ArrayLists and Iterators for your objects and run for loops in your threads to check for collisions. You will also need to ensure that you're accessing the same instances of the objects - just things to keep in mind moving forward! I hope this helps and wish you all the best.

Comment: yes sir! can I have some samples? thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope this provides the answer you are looking for.